# Code added in edit by unrelated user

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, code, specific-edit

While editing a moment ago, I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14568863) which was made by a user seemingly unrelated to the OP.

The edit however added the full code that should have been in the question, which is fine in theory, however the code was never posted anywhere accessible to the editor, it is not in an image linked in the question's content, nor in the comments.

Is the editor actually the same person trying to farm points from edits?

As a side note, the given comment is ":D don't say thanks to me" which seems weird too.

Comment: OP had posted the code in the answer as he was newbie and I edited the post and flaged the answer as it was the code of the question :-)

Comment: @maven hi, thanks for replying directly - in future try to explain edits a little better and it'll all be good!

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073078/crash-my-android-app-when-arrayadapter-set-to-spinner?noredirect=1#comment69404483_41073078) I was not aware that so many people watch the edits ;D

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre. Good call, posting on Meta.

Comment: "Is the editor actually the same person trying to farm points from edits?" why is doing the right thing seen as something bad? Can't we simply infer from context?

Comment: @Braiam right, and from the given context, where the code was posted nowhere at all (as far as I could see with only 2k rep), I inferred that something bad was being done.

Comment: @maven Suggested edits go into an edit review queue for approval, so they may be seen by anyone working that queue, as well as anyone who visits the question page while the edit is still pending. And of course, the full edit history is also stored indefinitely.

Comment: @maven (cont) People in the edit review queue just see the info relating to the edit, not the full question page, so they generally won't see the full context of the edit, and while they _can_ click the relevant link to get to the question page it slows down the review process if they have to visit every question that they're reviewing. So it's a Good Idea to provide the reviewers with helpful edit comments.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre `Is the editor actually the same person trying to farm points from edits?` That line hurted me alot .. I am not hunting for reps .. I just want SO to be more helpful and accurate for the future readers ..  earning **reps** won't going to give me money :-) *next time use words wisely*

Comment: @maven, it is unfortunate that you have been hurt by Alfie's words. Alfie did not say *you* were farming for rep, but suggested the possibility that the OP might be doing so from a second account. However, both of you could have done things which would have prevented this situation from arising. You could have provided an edit summary that explained what you were doing. Edit summaries are required and should reflect what you are doing in the edit. For instance, you could have said something like "Moving code into the question which the OP added as an answer." (continued)

Comment: @maven (continued) On the other hand, Alfie might have seen the answer with the code from the OP by opening the question in another tab. Quite possibly, even if Alfie had opened the question (s)he may not have been able to see the answer due to the answer already being deleted (it was deleted prior to the edit completing review). However, suggested edits + the edit summary are really expected to stand on their own, unless the edit summary says to go look at something. Please learn from this that meaningful edit summaries are important; provide ones which reflect what you did in the edit.

Answer (score 13):

The code *was* posted by the OP, in an answer to the question. The answer is now deleted (see below), so you can't see it anymore, unless you have [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). So the suggested edit makes sense, but I don't know if it is enough to salvage the question. The OP also needs to provide an error message and/or stack trace.

I agree that this is hard to judge for a reviewer. The editor could have made this clear in the edit summary (instead of *:D don't say thanks to me*), but (s)he probably thought this was obvious, because at the time of editing, the answer was still visible. While you don't see answers when reviewing a question, you can't expect a <100 user to know this, and you would at least have been able to view the answer in a separate browser tab.

---

> Is the editor actually the same person trying to farm points from edits?

That would of course be forbidden, but if (s)he intended to do that, it would have been easier to approve the edit right away (you can do this if you're the author of a post), instead of letting the review queue decide.

> [image: screenshot with deleted answer]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, there should really be a way for someone doing a review to see that this is the case, because from my perspective that looks very dodgy

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre agreed, the editor should've mentioned something meaningful in the edit summary

Comment: Yeah, that user seems to use that edit summary as their standard. I'll ping 'em a request to not do that.

Comment: @MikeM. well spotted, good idea!

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for suggesting me. OP had posted the code in the answer as he was newbie and I edited the post and flaged the answer as it was the code of the question :-)